# Will Adaptec raid 2405 card work in Asus Crosshair Formula IV MOBO

Tags: vmware-esxi, hardware-raid, pci-express

Will this PCIe 8 lane Raid card [Adaptec 2405](http://www.adaptec.com/en-US/products/Controllers/Hardware/sas/entry/SAS-2405/)

Work in this Motherboard [Crosshair Formula IV](http://uk.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=kPGmtxee5RsQVsXG)

Having never seen a PCIe slot Im not sure and just want to check before ordering.

TIA

UPDATE:

What essentialy I am looking for is to find out if this PICe x8 card will work in this motherboard on a PCIe level.   I am satisfied that ESXi will work on this MB and with this Raid card.  Apparently some MB only allow Graphics cards to be used in certain PCIe slots hence my caution. See [Why does the Adaptec PCI Express card not work in a PCIe x16 slot?](http://ask.adaptec.com/scripts/adaptec_tic.cfg/php.exe/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=16991&p_created=1269955514&p_sid=9_xZgA3k&p_accessibility=0&p_redirect=&p_lva=14662&p_sp=cF9zcmNoPTEmcF9zb3J0X2J5PSZwX2dyaWRzb3J0PSZwX3Jvd19jbnQ9MTc4LDE3OCZwX3Byb2RzPTU0JnBfY2F0cz0mcF9wdj0xLjU0JnBfY3Y9JnBfc2VhcmNoX3R5cGU9YW5zd2Vycy5zZWFyY2hfbmwmcF9wYWdlPTI*&p_li=&p_topview=1)

Comment: None of the links are working, please edit and post them correctly.

Comment: That looks a lot like a desktop motherboard.  Is this really a serverfault question?

Comment: It is a desktop board but Im planning to build a ESXi whitebox.

Comment: The more information you can provide, the more likely you are to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [VMware Compatibility Guide](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php):

ESXi supports it.